# different size of byte after convert back image to byte Windows Phone

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone, byte

I've changed bytes to base64string and get the string length: 80,000.

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
e.ChosenPhoto.CopyTo(memoryStream);
byte[] result = memoryStream.ToArray();
var base64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(result);
```

code above, give me the string length: 80,0000

But after I convert bytes into image, and convert back image into bytes. and then changed bytes to base64string, I get the string length: 170,000.

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
e.ChosenPhoto.CopyTo(memoryStream);
byte[] result = memoryStream.ToArray();
var base64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(result);


Image myImage = new Image();
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
myImage.Source = bmp;

BitmapImage bm = img.Source as BitmapImage;
base64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(image2byte(bm));
```

and the code for image2byte

```
private byte[] image2byte(BitmapImage myimage)
{
   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
   WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(myimage);
   wb.SaveJpeg(ms, myimage.PixelWidth, myimage.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
   return ms.ToArray();
}
```

above code give the string length of base64: 170,000

does anyone know why this can happen?
I used this method on Windows Phone.

Comment: Show some code. Your description is confusing.

Comment: Most likely the problem is that the pixel format of your new image is using more bits per pixel than the original image. Also, are you certain that your `image2byte` method does the same thing as `e.ChosenPhoto.CopyTo(memoryStream)`?

Comment: @JimMischel yes, not sure that the method does the same thing. Do you think that the reason why the length of base64 different is in that two methods ?
that's the point of my question. why the result is different?

Comment: I think it's either that the methods are different or that the images themselves are different. You need to check both things.